# Recuperar sección borrada sin afectar inserciones en Git

Tags: git

Disculpas si mi pregunta es muy básica pero hasta el momento no he logrado saber si existe una forma o no de resolver lo siguiente:

Trabajando en un archivo F en un repositorio de Git:

- Creo una nueva rama A donde borro toda una sección del archivo F y hago commit del cambio (borrado de sección) y sigo trabajando añadiendo nuevas secciones.
- Recibo instrucción de que el borrado de la sección fue un error y necesitamos incluir dicha sección de nuevo.
- Obviamente si hago un reset a un estado previo al borrado de aquella sección, pierdo todas las inserciones posteriores, lo cual no quiero (obviamente puedo copiar lo que quiero mantener antes de hacer el reset para después pegarlo...pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna solución más elegante.)

He intentado también:

- Antes del borrado de la sección en la rama creada, creo una nueva rama para continuar trabajando en el archivo F con las inserciones, pensando erróneamente que al hacer un merge o un rebase, con la rama donde el archivo aun mantiene la sección eliminada, se mantendrían todas las secciones...sin embargo, no es así...al hacer el merge se añaden las nuevas secciones, pero desaparece también la sección eliminada.

¿Hay alguna forma de fusionar ramas manteniendo las adiciones pero no considerando las eliminaciones? para volver a una situación previa al borrado de una sección pero incorporando todas las inserciones posteriores.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias crearte una Rama en un punto anterior a los cambios y añadirle solo los cambios que te interesen usando `Cherrypick Commit`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Funcionó!!!, hice un git cherry-pick desde la rama que mantenía la sección eliminada, seleccionando un commit de la nueva rama  donde añadí las nuevas secciones; y se han integrado perfectamente ambos trabajos. No conocía este comando, muchísimas gracias de nuevo.